# Is there a way to tell if the sun is rising or setting by looking at a picture and not knowing which coast it was taken at?

Tags: astronomy

Looking through some pictures after watching "The Zero Theorem" it crossed my mind.

Comment: This question is obviously completely off-topic here.  It *might*, however, be on topic at [Photography SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Springing to mind as a possibility: sunset images may have more heat distortion since they are shot over warmer surfaces.

Comment: @Flimzy [It's already there](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26776).

Comment: In my opinion that is probably not a good fit. Some Astronomy or physics based SE would have the required knowledge to tackle a general, "do sunsets look different than sunrises" question.